# Pair new device over wifi not working in android studio

Tags: android

I'm trying to pair device which is connected with USB,but QR code and pairing code doesn't work and stuck in searching for device.
I tried to connect using the command:
`adb connect [phone_ip]:[port]`
in the terminal box, and it told me it is connected, but I still can't choose the device as you can see below:[cannot use the device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLYul.png)

what can I do?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Android studio (in my experience) does prevent connection to physical device over WiFi at random.   I tried all kinds of things but ultimately most basic IT support advice works for me every-time = **Fully restart everything, both PC and physical device.**

Answer (score 0):

I also just experienced this, have you tried it in the terminal: adb connect [phone_ip]:[port]
or in cmd prompt, what I do is check if %PATH% is correct to run adb and restart AS, then everything goes smoothly